# How to call Route path 2,3 followed by 5,6 and if it is 5,6 i should redirect to another page

Tags: reactjs

```js
class Landing extends React.Component {   
    
    render() {
        
        const {userLogin:{loggedUser},page}  = this.props
        //console.log(loggedUser)
        return (
            <div className="right-section">
                <Header page={page}/>
                {loggedUser && 
                    loggedUser.userType &&
                     loggedUser.userType ==='0' ?
                      <Report /> : loggedUser.userType ==='1' ? <AudioToTrack /> 
                      : (loggedUser.userType ==='2' || loggedUser.userType ==='3' || loggedUser.userType ==='5' || loggedUser.userType ==='6') ? <QADashBoard /> : loggedUser.userType ==='4' ? <SADashboard /> :  <p>Loading ....!</p>}
            </div>
        )
    }
}



const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    //console.log(state)
    const { AudioToTrackReducer, userLogin,page } = state
    return {
        AudioToTrackReducer,
        userLogin,
        page
    }
}


export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, {})(Landing))
```

How to call Route path  2,3 followed by 5,6 and if it is 5,6 i should redirect to another page. tried using above code for calling and getting some page redirection. but i want logic for, if it is 5,6 then only i schould  redirect to anther page.

Comment: Consider refactoring your code a bit to make it easier to read. Nesting ternary statements are bad practice and make your code much more difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
  onSubmit = () => {
         if(loggedUser.userType ==='5' || loggedUser.userType ==='6'){
             return  <Redirect  to="/otherPage/" />
         }
      }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. but according to my code there is no onSubmit, by default if its a 5 and 6 i should redirect to another page.

Comment: according to above code i want redirection to another page, if the paths are 5 and 6.

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Comment: <Route exact strict path="/:id" component={WillMatch} @Tdhanunjay then try this one using will match you can match your default route 5 and 6 and put a condition if the match then redirect to the page where you want.   <Redirect  to="/Specific page/" />